# Trying to run Scheme in org mode

Tags: org-babel, scheme

I installed geiser, set my default scheme to guile, and enabled scheme support but I can't seem to get it to work. I am getting this output and am not sure what to make of it.

```
#+begin_src scheme :results output
(define test (lambda (v) v))
(test 'test)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Unknown meta command: geiser-eval
: $2 = #f
: $3 = test
: While compiling expression:
: Syntax error:
: unknown location: unexpected syntax in form ()
: scheme@(guile-user) [3]>
```

Comment: Can you start `guile` from the command line? If yes, can you start it with `M-x geiser RET`?  IOW, cut out the Org mode middleman: if it does not work, then the geiser setup needs work. If it does, then you can concentrate on the Org mode interface.

Comment: What version of Org mode are you running? `M-x org-version` will tell.

Comment: I'm using version 9.5.

Comment: I just needed scheme because I didn't get racket working in org but I have racket working (with #lang racket in the code block) and I don't need scheme working I'm just super neurotic and the thought of something not working drives me mad.